# mutliprocessing.Pool.add_sync() eating up memory

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I want to use multithreading to make my script faster...
I'm still new to this.  The Python doc assumes you already understand threading and what-not.

So...

I have code that looks like this

```
from itertools import izip
from multiprocessing import Pool

p = Pool()
for i, j in izip(hugeseta, hugesetb):
    p.apply_async(number_crunching, (i, j))
```

Which gives me great speed!

However, *hugeseta* and *hugesetb* are **really huge**.  Pool keeps all of the *i* s and *j* s in memory after they've finished their job (basically, print output to stdout).  Is there any to del *i*, and *j* after they complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer but I used `Pool.imap()`instead:

```
for i in p.imap(do, izip(Fastitr(seqsa, filetype='fastq'), \
        Fastitr(seqsb, filetype='fastq'))):
    pass
```

Which works beautifully and garbage collects as expected however it feels funny having a `for` loop with nothing but `pass` actually do something useful.

Answer (score 0):

The [del statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement) deletes object references, so can free up memory when the garbage collector runs.

```
from itertools import izip
from multiprocessing import Pool

p = Pool()
for i, j in izip(hugeseta, hugesetb):
    p.apply_async(number_crunching, (i, j))

del i, j
```

Comment: Where would I put del?

I tried checking the pool for dead workers, but there are never any more workers than cores.

So where are all the _i_ s and _j_ s being stored?

Comment: @Austin Just `del` i and j as soon as you are done with them.

Comment: I meant while the loop is running.  If I run without Pool, memory use flattens out.  If I run it with Pool, old _i_ s and _j_ s don't get garbage collected.